# Trying to update a text file

Tags: c#

**I'm trying to replace a certain line in a .txt file when I click the Update Button**

This is what my program looks like
[http://i.imgur.com/HKu4bGo.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeUNn.png)

This is my code so far

```
        string[] arrLine = File.ReadAllLines("Z:/Daniel/SortedAccounts.txt");
        arrLine[accountComboBox.SelectedIndex] = "#1#" + firstNameInfoBox.Text + "#2#" + lastNameInfoBox.Text + "#3#" + emailInfoBox.Text + "#4#" + phoneNumberInfoBox.Text + "#5#EMAIL#6#";
        File.WriteAllLines("Z:/Daniel/SortedAccounts.txt", arrLine);
```

This is what's inside SortedAccounts.txt

> #1#Bob#2#Smith#3#Bob@Smith.com#4#5551234567#5#EMAIL#6#
>   #1#Dan#2#Lastyy#3#Daniel@Lastyy.com#4#5551234567#5#EMAIL#6#

The ComboBox is in the order as the Txt File.

So I get the same Index as the selected item in the ComboBox. And then I want to delete that line and then add a new line that same txt file with the updated information.

My code isn't doing this for some reason though and I can't figure it out

Comment: What *is* your code doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out using List to easily remove an entry at a certain index. Don't forget to reload the combobox data source when the file is updated to avoid index mismatch etc..

```
List<string> arrLine = File.ReadAllLines("Z:/Daniel/SortedAccounts.txt").ToList();
arrLine.RemoveAt(accountComboBox.SelectedIndex);
string newLine = "#1#" + firstNameInfoBox.Text + "#2#" + lastNameInfoBox.Text + "#3#" + emailInfoBox.Text + "#4#" + phoneNumberInfoBox.Text + "#5#EMAIL#6#";
arrLine.Add(newLine);
File.WriteAllLines("Z:/Daniel/SortedAccounts.txt", arrLine);
```